# APN push notification from java server?

Tags: java, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I am using the p12 file to connect to APN server using java code but am getting error:javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure

Code:

```
private String token="c585ca35 21468c52 e7285b15 5441fcd3 77b50594 c05000c1 165aa025a87a1660";
private String host = "gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com";
private int port = 2195;
private String payload = "{\"aps\":{\"alert\":\"Message from Java o_O\"}}";
  try {
    KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");

    keyStore.load(getClass().getResourceAsStream("E://workspace//Product//javatest//lib//Certificates_key.p12"), "ducont".toCharArray());
  //  keyStore.load(getClass().getResourceAsStream("Certificates_key.p12"), "ducont".toCharArray());
    KeyManagerFactory keyMgrFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
    keyMgrFactory.init(keyStore, "ducont".toCharArray());

    SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
    sslContext.init(keyMgrFactory.getKeyManagers(), null, null);
    SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = sslContext.getSocketFactory();

    SSLSocket sslSocket = (SSLSocket) sslSocketFactory.createSocket(host, port);
    String[] cipherSuites = sslSocket.getSupportedCipherSuites();
    sslSocket.setEnabledCipherSuites(cipherSuites);
    sslSocket.startHandshake();

    char[] t = token.toCharArray();
    byte[] b = Hex.decodeHex(t);

    OutputStream outputstream = sslSocket.getOutputStream();

    outputstream.write(0);
    outputstream.write(0);
    outputstream.write(32);
    outputstream.write(b);
    outputstream.write(0);
    outputstream.write(payload.length());
    outputstream.write(payload.getBytes());

    outputstream.flush();
    outputstream.close();

} catch (Exception exception) {
    exception.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Do you have any further details?

Comment: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure

Comment: You can check the code for more ref..